# Flex button without gradient

Tags: apache-flex, button, gradient

how can I create a simple button in Flex (SDK 3.3) without any gradient or border color? My CSS is shown below. I still get gradient and different border color, I just want a plain, square, solid color button.

thanks!

```
Button {
    fontWeight:normal;
    color:white;
    fillAlphas: 1, 1, 1, 1;
    fillColors: "0x0087B8", "0x0087B8","0x4A1870", "0x4A1870";
    cornerRadius: 0;
    focusAlpha: 1;
    borderColor:"0x0087B8";
    borderAlpha:1;
    textRollOverColor: white;

}
```

Comment: Just want to say, if you upgrade to Flex 4 or later; the Spark Button makes it real easy to do this w/ a custom skin.  To remove the gradient, shouldn't your fill colors all be identical?

Comment: agree with Flextras above, fill colors should be identical, generally speaking in Flex 3 I'd go with setting a programmatic skin and just do the simple drawing if you're going for very stripped down looking and aren't afraid to get into a bit of the drawing with the graphics class.  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinning_5.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your input, I had to create a programmtic skin like this:

```
    public class TIMPButtonSkin extends ProgrammaticSkin
{
    public var backgroundFillColor:Number;
    public var lineThickness:Number;

    public function TIMPButtonSkin()
    {
        super();

    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(w:Number, h:Number):void {

        var btn:Button = parent as Button;
        btn.buttonMode = true;

        switch (name) {
            case "upSkin":
                backgroundFillColor = 0x0087B8;
                break;
            case "overSkin":
                backgroundFillColor = 0x4A1870;
                break;
            case "downSkin":
                backgroundFillColor = 0x4A1870;
                break;
            case "disabledSkin":
                break;
        }

        // Draw the box using the new values.
        var g:Graphics = graphics;
        g.clear();
        g.beginFill(backgroundFillColor,1.0);
        g.lineStyle(lineThickness, 0xFF0000);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g.endFill();
    }
}
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
Button {
fontWeight:normal;
color:white;
cornerRadius: 0;
textRollOverColor: white;
textSelectedColor:white;
skin: ClassReference("TIMP.TIMPButtonSkin");
```

}